# Failing to give assumptions to find the solution of a Ricatti equations

Tags: differential-equations, assumptions

I'm working on a Riccatti equation that I know has the following property:

```
b^2 - a c > 0
```

I've been trying to use this as an assumption in DSolve, but no matter what I get more general solutions and I'm not able to simplify them to the one that works.

```
DSolve[{a (FC[h])^2 - 2 b FC[h] + c - D[FC[h], h] == 0, FC[0] == 0}, FC[h], h, Assumptions -> b^2 - a c > 0 ]
```

There is a solution I know works:

```
q := Sqrt[b^2 - a c] 
FCT[h_] := (c (1 - E^(-2 q (h))))/(q + b + (q - b) E^(-2 q (h)));
```

I think I'm not able to obtain this solution in DSolve because I'm failing to give the assumption correctly. This previous solution FCT[h] only works for b^2-ac>0 which is exactly what I need. Any guidance in this problem would he highly appreciated :)

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Jim Baldwin's solution is entirely satisfactory (+1), it is possible to obtain the desired expression without the additional assumptions.  Begin by solving the ODE *without* the boundary condition.

```
s = FC[h] /. Flatten@DSolve[{a (FC[h])^2 - 2 b FC[h] + c - D[FC[h], h] == 0}, 
    FC[h], h, Assumptions -> b^2 - a c > 0]
(* (b - Sqrt[b^2 - a c] Tanh[Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h + Sqrt[b^2 - a c] C[1]])/a *)
```

Now, obtaining`C[1]` by `Solve[0 == s /. h -> 0, C[1]]` gives the same ugly expressions that `DSolve` with the boundary condition gives.

```
Flatten@Solve[0 == s /. h -> 0, C[1]]
(* {C[1] -> -(ArcCosh[-(Sqrt[-b^2 + a c]/(Sqrt[a] Sqrt[c]))]/Sqrt[b^2 - a c]), 
    C[1] -> ArcCosh[-(Sqrt[-b^2 + a c]/(Sqrt[a] Sqrt[c]))]/Sqrt[b^2 - a c], 
    C[1] -> -(ArcCosh[Sqrt[-b^2 + a c]/(Sqrt[a] Sqrt[c])]/Sqrt[b^2 - a c]), 
    C[1] -> ArcCosh[Sqrt[-b^2 + a c]/(Sqrt[a] Sqrt[c])]/Sqrt[b^2 - a c]} *)
```

Instead, simply observe that `C[1]` is

```
C[1] -> ArcTanh[b/Sqrt[b^2 - a c]]/Sqrt[b^2 - a c]
```

Then,

```
s /. C[1] -> ArcTanh[b/Sqrt[b^2 - a c]]/Sqrt[b^2 - a c]
(* (b - Sqrt[b^2 - a c] Tanh[Sqrt[b^2 - a c] h + ArcTanh[b/Sqrt[b^2 - a c]]])/a *)

Simplify[TrigToExp[%]] /. Sqrt[b^2 - a c] -> q
(* (c (-1 + E^(2 h q)))/(b (-1 + E^(2 h q)) + (1 + E^(2 h q)) q) *)
```

and

```
Simplify[% == (c (1 - E^(-2 q (h))))/(q + b + (q - b) E^(-2 q (h)))]
(* True *)
```

It may be that the additional assumptions are needed when working with the `DSolve` solution with boundary condition, because it introduces factors of `Sqrt[a]` and `Sqrt[c]` that eventually drop out of the simplification but appear to require that `a > 0` and `c > 0` during intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer... If one assumes a few more conditions, then the usual simplification works fine:

```
sol = FC[h] /. Simplify[TrigToExp[DSolve[{a (FC[h])^2 - 2 b FC[h] + c - D[FC[h], h] == 0, FC[0] == 0}, FC[h], h]],
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, b^2 - a c > 0}]
```

$\left\{-\frac{-a b c \left(e^{2 h \sqrt{b^2-a c}}+3\right)+a c \sqrt{b^2-a c} \left(e^{2 h \sqrt{b^2-a c}}-1\right)+4 b^2 \sqrt{b^2-a c}+4 b^3}{a \left(a c \left(e^{2 h \sqrt{b^2-a c}}+1\right)-2 b \sqrt{b^2-a c}-2 b^2\right)},-\frac{c \left(\sqrt{b^2-a c}+b\right) \left(e^{2 h \sqrt{b^2-a c}}-1\right)}{a c \left(e^{2 h \sqrt{b^2-a c}}+1\right)-2 b \left(\sqrt{b^2-a c}+b\right) e^{2 h \sqrt{b^2-a c}}}\right\}$

And then we compare the two equations:

```
Simplify[sol[[2]] == FCT[h]]
(* True *)
```

This is not to say that the additional conditions ($a>0$, $b>0$, and $c>0$) are essential to the solution.  It's only that *Mathematica* simplifies things enough in that case to show equality.

By leaving off those additional restrictions the resulting equation (`sol[[2]]`) is (I think) what you want but needs to be simplified more "by hand" as it involves simplifications under square roots.  At least how to tell *Mathematica* to simplify those things more automatically is beyond what I know how to do.